# How to build tenant level metrics counter for GCP dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, metrics

Currently i am trying to create custom metrics for GCP dataflow job using apache beam Metrics and wanted to check if we can track/group counters based on tenant. For instance we have events generated by multiple tenants and all the events are processed in a dataflow job (which writes to big table) and i want to add metrics filter to group them by tenant so we could see elmentsAdded at tenant level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Beam Metrics; they don't have the ability to set extra metric fields such as tenant.

However, you can use the [Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) directly from you pipeline code to export data into Cloud Monitoring with any schema you'd like

Comment: Is there any examples?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation for the API.  There's nothing Beam- or Dataflow-specific you need to do here.